# observable as the model of a form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following form:

```
<form *ngIf="model$ | async; let model" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #modelForm="ngForm">
    <input name="model.id" [(ngModel)]="model.data" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the component:

```
export class ModelComponent implements OnInit {
    model$: Observable<Model>;
    ....
    onSubmit() {
    }
}
```

In the `onSubmit()` event, how can I get the updated model object and sends it over using the HTTP client?

Comment: Have you tried ` (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(model)"`?

Comment: @user184994 that's it! thanks